# Can I use sub-directories in the "templates" directory?

Tags: 8

I created a module that contains a large number of custom templates. They are only used for the module's output; they don't override any existing template file.

I would like to place these templates in sub-directories inside the *templates* directory.

If I place a template in a sub-directory and set a block's `#theme` to `'account/list_block'`, for example, the block isn't rendered, but I don't get errors.

When I keep the template in the sub-directory but set `#theme` to `'list_block'`, I get the following error.

> Template "modules/contrib/mymodule/templates/list-block.html.twig" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "modules/contrib/mymodule/templates/list-block.html.twig" in the Drupal theme registry.).

From the first example, it seems that Drupal knows the template exists and where to find it, but it doesn't render it.

Is using sub-directories in the "templates" directory possible?

Comment: Not just possible, should be very easy :) What does your `hook_theme()` implementation look like? You just need to set the `template` key there to whatever makes sense (e.g. `'account/list_block'`)

Comment: Nice, I would guess they haven't done away with hooks completely because they need advanced logic sometimes and yaml doesn't really give you that. But yeah, I was a bit surprised when I saw D8 that everything hadn't been moved to subscribed events. Maybe that's too clunky, who knows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to specify the path to the template in `hook_theme()`, eg

```
function MYMODULE_theme() {
  return [
    'list_block' => [
      'variables' => [],
      // Underscores are not converted to dashes automatically in this case.
      'template' => 'account/list-block',
    ],
  ];
}
```